# How to make my Excel Sheet update automatically to trigger email sending based on cell value in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, volatile, auto-update

How can I make my Excel Sheet generate automated emails whenever the cell value becomes 45?

To do so I have created 2 Excel Workbooks. The first one (Workbook-1) contains a column, which calculates the actual number of days left to certain event (event date - Today()). The second one (Workbook-2) has the same column, but it simply takes these values from the (Workbook-1).

The purpose of the (Workbook-2) is to collect the most important data to be used in the email. For example, if for today the number of days left is 46, tomorrow it will be automatically updated in both workbooks and will become 45. Here is where I want the second workbook to trigger email sending without my further interference.

I have prepared the code below (for the Workbook-2) and it actually works with me, but just in 2 cases: 
1) when I manually copy and paste the formula in the corresponding cell, which value is already 45;
2) when I choose the corresponding cell and press Enter in the formula bar.

None of these options is suitable for me, as the idea was to automate the process.

**Here is the code:**

```
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("H2:H75"), Target)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 45 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target)
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(val)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim xMailSubject As String
    Dim xMailTo As String
    Dim xMailCc As String

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    xMailBody = "<b>Dear </b>" & "<b>" & val.Offset(0, -1).Value & "</b>" & "<b>!</b>" & "<br /><br />" & _
        "Hereby please be kindly informed, that the following offer will expire on " & "<span style='font-weight:bold'>" & val.Offset(0, -2).Value & "</span>" & "," & " that is, after " & val.Offset(0, 0).Value & " days from the date of this email." 

    xMailSubject = val.Offset(0, 1).Value
    xMailTo = val.Offset(0, 2).Value
    xMailCc = val.Offset(0, 3).Value

    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = xMailTo
        .CC = xMailCc
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = xMailSubject
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody
        .Display   
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the meanwhile, I have read a lot of articles on this matter, most of them recommend to use Application.Volatile method to force Excel recalculate the target cell values (in my case just a single column), others recommend to force excel auto-update each second. Ultimately, most of them are not comprehensive at all. So which one is the most suitable for my particular case?

Comment: Hi Daniel, given that this would appear to be something that might only be run once daily, perhaps you could you the workbook open event to trigger the email?

Comment: Do you intend to let the workbook(s)  opened and you expect that next day at 00:01 the Excel function `Today()` will automatically change its value, I'm afraid things do not happen in this way.  Opening the workbook, changing something on the sheet, saving etc. In order to be changed, only an event able to trigger `Application.Calculate` will do that. So, you must use a timer, `Application.OnTime` in a recursive function or something similar, able to force `Calculate`...

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem comes from the fact that nothing triggers the `Application.Calculation`. The `Today()` Excel formula does not return a  new date if the workbook is opened and nothing obliges Excel to calculate.
So, I would suggest you to use `Workbook_Open()` event in order to call, at a specific time a function, which will change the date, making Excel cu calculate (if `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`). Then the function in discussion will recursively  work setting the next time to be operating:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.OnTime TimeSerial(0, 0, 0), "Date_Change"
End Sub

Sub Date_Change()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
    sh.Range("A2").Value = Date
    '"programming" the function to act nex time/day
    Application.OnTime TimeSerial(0, 0, 0), "Date_Change"
End Sub
```

The "A2" range value (or whatever range you will choose) must be the basis of calculations for that value able to trigger the sending mails function.